# Modify array keys of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
 $the_posted = Array
            (
    0 => Array
        (
            0 => 1,
            1 => 2,
            2 => 3,
            3 => 4,
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            0 => 5,
            1 => 6,
            2 => 7,
            3 => 8,
        )

);
```

whose keys i need to modify.I trying  to modify the array keys like

```
$all_array_keys = array_keys($the_posted);

 foreach ( array_keys($the_posted) as $k=>$v )
{
  $all_array_keys[$k]= rand();
}

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($all_array_keys);
  echo "<hr/>";
  print_r($the_posted);
  echo '<pre>';
```

I get this result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 25642
    [1] => 8731
)

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 8
        )

)
```

The change in keys is not reflected in the final array.How do i make this work?.

Comment: What does the result you want look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element), [PHP Change Array Keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308703/php-change-array-keys).

Comment: what a name you got there....

Comment: @rid: sorry but you are wrong. It is possible to change a key of an item. Please refer to my message below.

Comment: I agree that it's not clean, but the final result is exactly what this guy is trying to do, I think...

Comment: @rid: depends of the situation. Let's say you have a very large array, and only want to change a few keys. Building a completely new array would probably be more time consuming. That's probably a good thing to know how to use both solution. (and I actually do not care about downvote, I'm just trying to help ^^)

Comment: @No Idea For Name I ran out of ideas too for a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code :

```
foreach ( array_keys($the_posted) as $k=>$v )
{   
  $new_key = rand();
  $new_posted[$new_key] = $the_posted[$v];
  unset($the_posted[$v])
}
```

Here, we have created a new array `$new_posted` which will have data with new keys like this :

```
Array
(
    [28228] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [23341] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 8
        )

)
```

Comment: And, if and only if you're memory constrained (maybe you don't have a lot of allocated memory for PHP and the array is very big), you can also `unset($the_posted[$k])` at each iteration, which would keep the same memory footprint, at the expense of performance. But if memory is not a concern, it should be significantly faster without the `unset()`.

Comment: @rid : agreed with you.

Answer (score -1):

To change the key of an item, do something like this:

```
$the_posted[$newkey] = $the_posted[$oldkey];
unset($the_posted[$oldkey]);
```

So in your case:

```
foreach ( $the_posted as $k=>$v )
{
    $newkey = rand();
    while(isset($the_posted[$newkey]))
       $newkey = rand();
    $the_posted[$newkey] = $the_posted[$k];
    unset($the_posted[$k]);
}
```

Comment: True. I updated the code to fix the issue.