# Remap keys in each row of a 2d array to replace string keys with new string keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace, key

I have an array like the one below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Alex
            [age] => 30
            [place] => Texas                
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Larry
            [age] => 28
            [place] => Memphis

        )

)
```

How would I change the key names? Like "name" to "firstname", "age" to "years", "place" to "address"?

Comment: you can find an answer to your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308703/php-change-array-keys

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) is your friend,

```
$users = array_map(function($user) {
    return array(
        'firstname' => $user['name'],
        'years' => $user['age'],
        'location' => $user['place']
    );
}, $users);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/JXriDV).

Comment: @GuyT: This is a valid solution (a more functional approach than mine). But [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22096142/1438393) was downvoted too :/

Comment: I baffled too. At-least he should comment the reason for down vote.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `foreach` loop to iterate over your array, and then use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array_combine) in conjunction with [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) to create the new array:

```
$keys = array('firstname', 'years', 'address');
foreach ($array as & $subarr) {
    $subarr = array_combine($keys, array_values($subarr));
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Alex
            [years] => 30
            [address] => Texas
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Larry
            [years] => 28
            [address] => Memphis
        )

)
```

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/106982)

Comment: I'm baffled by the downvote; it would be nice for the downvoter to explain why he/she thinks this is an unhelpful and/or incorrect response so I can, perhaps, improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way to do this is to create a new array and assign each value with old key to value with new key.

```
<?php
    //$originalArray is array from the question.
    for($i=0; $i<=count($originalArray); $i++){
        $originalArray[$i] = rekeyArray($originalArray[$i]);
    }

    function rekeyArray($a){
        $result = array();

        if(isset($a['name']))
        $result['firstname'] = $a['name'];

        if(isset($a['age']))
        $result['years'] = $a['age'];

        if(isset($a['place']))
        $result['address'] = $a['place'];

        return $result;
    }
?>
```