# How to change array keys

Tags: php, arrays

how do i change keys of my array like:

```
$arrData = array('key1'=>'data1', 'key2'=>'data2')
```

to:

```
$arrData = array('newKey1'=>'data1', 'newKey2'=>'data2')
```

I like it to be done withing a single stmt like:

```
$arrData = changeKey(array('newKey1'=>'data1', 'newKey2'=>'data2'))
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/) might help.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/

Comment: create a simple function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$arrData['newKey1'] = $arrData['key1'];
unset($arrData['key1']);
```

[UPDATE]:

```
function changeKey($array, $newkey, $oldkey)
{   
        $array[$newkey] = $arrData[$oldkey];
        unset($array[$oldkey]);
        return $array;  
}

$array = changeKey($array, 'key1', 'key2');
```