# How to change array key of this array?

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

This the array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [due_date] => 2011-09-23
            [due_amount] => 10600.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [due_date] => 2011-10-23
            [due_amount] => 10600.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [due_date] => 2011-11-23
            [due_amount] => 10600.00
        )
)
```

how to change **id** to **u_id** in this array?

Regards

Comment: What have you tried so far so it saves our time trying what you have already tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
array_walk_recursive($array, 'changeIDkey');

function changeIDkey($item, &$key)
{
    if ($key == 'id') $key = 'u_id';
}
```

PHP Manual: [array_walk_recursive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

**EDIT**

This will not work for the reason @salathe gave in the Comments below. Working on alternative.

**ACTUAL ANSWER**

```
function changeIDkey(&$value,$key)
{
    if ($value === "id") $value = "u_id";
}

$new = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $keys = array_keys($value);
    array_walk($keys,"changeIDkey");
    $new[] = array_combine($keys,array_values($value));
}

var_dump($new); //verify
```

Where `$array` is your input array. Note that this will only work with your current array structure (two-dimensions, changes keys on only second dimension).

The loop iterates through the inner arrays changing "id" to "u_id" in the keys and then recombines the new keys with the old values.

Comment: Take heed of the note on the `array_walk()` manual page, which is just as applicable for `array_walk_recursive()`: *Only the values of the `array` may potentially be changed; its structure cannot be altered, i.e., the programmer cannot add, unset or reorder elements. If the callback does not respect this requirement, the behavior of this function is undefined, and unpredictable.*

Comment: @salathe: Yes, just noticed that. Working on alternative.

Comment: This is just awful, what's wrong with a simple `array_walk()` and  the loop body of @nobody's answer as the callback?

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach( $array as &$element ) {
    $element['u_id'] = $element['id'];
    unset( $element['id'] );
}
```