# How do I grab a word before underscore on my array ouput

Tags: php, arrays

This is my current array which keep a first character from the value

```
Array ( [n] => Array ( [0] => name_john ) [a] => Array ( [0] => age_30 ) )

foreach ($queryArray as $key) {
    $inArray[$key[0]][] = $key;
}
```

Question : How do I grab a word before underscore and change the array to be like

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [0] => name_john
        )

    [age] => Array
        (
            [0] => age_30
        )

)
```

Comment: Where do you get the array from? If possible you should solve the actual problem and create the array with an appropriate structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse out the word before the underscore, use explode:

```
// $key = name_john
$split_key = explode('_',$key);
// $split_key[0] equals name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$pieces = explode("_", $key);
echo $pieces[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$inArray[$key[0]][] = substr($key, 0, strpos($key, '_'));
```

But if you make the array using the "key" as the assoc. index, like

```
Array ( [n] => Array ( ["name"] => john ) [a] => Array ( ["age"] => 30 ) )
```

Then you can

```
foreach ($queryArray as $subArr) {
    foreach($subArr as $subkey => $val){
        $inArray[$subkey][] = $val;
    }
}
```

and you should get an array like

```
Array
(
    ["name"] => "john"

    ["age"] => 30
)
```

Tho its not the "desired" output, might be cleaner and easier to use for what it seems like you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

- To split the value, use `explode('_', $value)` and get the first item of the returned array.
- To modify an array in a foreach, add a reference on the array
- To change a key of an element in an array, check this thread: [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

**Working example:** ([codepad here](http://codepad.org/tmSJEUmH))

```
<?php

$array = array('n' => Array(0 => 'name_john'), 'a' => Array('0' => 'age_30'));

foreach ($array as &$value) {
    foreach ($value as $oldkey => $name) {
        $chunks = explode('_', $name);
        $newkey = $chunks[0];
        // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element
        $value[$newkey] = $value[$oldkey];
        unset($value[$oldkey]);
    }
}
var_dump($array);
```

**Output:**

```
array
  'n' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'name_john' (length=9)
  'a' => &
    array
      'age' => string 'age_30' (length=6)
```

Comment: It's work when have a single `name_` and getting blank if have twice `name_` example array `$array = array('n' => Array(0 => 'name_john', 1 => 'name_peter'), 'a' => Array('0' => 'age_30'));`

Answer (score 0):

Try put this inside your foreach statement :)

```
$string = strstr($key, '_', true); 
echo $string; // prints ewverything before the '_'
```