# Change array key without changing order

Tags: php, arrays

You can ["change" the key of an array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element) simply by setting the new key and removing the old:

```
$array[$newKey] = $array[$oldKey];
unset($array[$oldKey]);
```

But this will move the key to the end of the array.

Is there some elegant way to change the key without changing the order?

(PS: This question is just out of conceptual interest, not because I need it anywhere.)

Comment: I'd imagine some ugly construct with array_splice() and array_slice() would do the trick

Comment: @MarcB That wouldn't work with string keys though.

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer, but what in the world are the semantics of `$arr[$oldKey]` if this works as an argument to a function which removes `$oldKey` from `$arr`? I think PHP might be more interesting than I previously thought, will have to look into this …

Comment: @FelixDombek I'm not sure I get you. `$array[$oldKey]` will just return the value with the key `$oldKey`.

Comment: @NikiC That's what I also thought, but if it evaluates to, say, 5, then how does `unset()` delete the element from the array? How does PHP even know in *which* array it should delete the value 5?

Comment: Ah, that's what you mean. `unset` is not a normal function, it's a language construct. So it's not like `$array[$oldKey]` is evaluated and passed to `unset()`.

Comment: Why do you care about "order" if this is an associative array?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Tested and works :)

```
function replace_key($array, $old_key, $new_key) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    if (false === $index = array_search($old_key, $keys, true)) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf('Key "%s" does not exist', $old_key));
    }
    $keys[$index] = $new_key;
    return array_combine($keys, array_values($array));
}

$array = [ 'a' => '1', 'b' => '2', 'c' => '3' ];    
$new_array = replace_key($array, 'b', 'e');
```

Comment: +1 Though you probably should add an error handler for the case that `$old_key` is not in the array.

Comment: Only if the key doesn't exist then replace the first one. Add an if clause, and youre ok;)

Comment: Wouldn't one be better off returning the unchanged array instead of throwing an exception?

Answer (score 12):

Something like this may also work:

```
$langs = array("EN" => "English", 
        "ZH" => "Chinese", 
        "DA" => "Danish",
        "NL" => "Dutch", 
        "FI" => "Finnish", 
        "FR" => "French",
        "DE" => "German");
$json = str_replace('"EN":', '"en":', json_encode($langs));
print_r(json_decode($json, true));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [en] => English
    [ZH] => Chinese
    [DA] => Danish
    [NL] => Dutch
    [FI] => Finnish
    [FR] => French
    [DE] => German
)
```

Comment: I personally find this solution very elegant! +1

Comment: Me too.  This works wonderful for removing dashes/underscores from XML tag names when using Zend_Config_XML::toArray().  In my case, the data is options for select elements w/ optgroups.  My optgroup names were XML tags, and the titles had dashes.  This worked well for that.

Comment: I dont find this elegant. Very dangerous.

Comment: This only works because the example data is a very specific case. If the key to be replaced exists as any value then that would also be replaced. This is not a safe solution.

Comment: @PhilHilton: No where I mentioned this to be a panacea kind of solution. This is just a shorthand work around. Moreover having `"EN":` (quoted string followed by colon) in value is very rare.

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to simply use a foreach iterating over the array and copying it to a new array, changing the key conditionally while iterating, e.g. if $key === 'foo' then dont use foo but bar:

```
function array_key_rename($array, $oldKey, $newKey) 
{
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $newArray[$key === $oldKey ? $newKey : $key] = $value;
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Another way would be to `serialize` the array, `str_replace` the serialized key and then `unserialize` back into an array again. That isnt particular elegant though and likely error prone, especially when you dont only have scalars or multidimensional arrays.

A third way - my favorite - would be you writing `array_key_rename` in C and proposing it for the PHP core ;)

Comment: Is $newArray accessible from outside the scope of foreach?

Comment: @nawfal yes, but not outside the function unless you assign the return value

Comment: OK. Bit strange to get used to PHP coming from another language :)

Answer (score 1):

Check keys existence before proceeding…
Otherwise the result can be catastrophic if the new key already exists... or unnecessary processing time/memory consumption if the key to be replaced does not exist.

```
function array_rename_key( array $array, $old_key, $new_key ) {
    // if $new_key already exists, or if $old_key doesn't exists
    if ( array_key_exists( $new_key, $array ) || ! array_key_exists( $old_key, $array ) ) {
        return $array;
    }

    $new_array = [];
    foreach ( $array as $k => $v ) {
        $new_array[ $k === $old_key ? $new_key : $k ] = $v;
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a double flip! At least that is all I can think of:

```
$array=("foo"=>"bar","asdf"=>"fdsa");
$array=array_flip($array);
$array["bar"]=>'newkey';
$array=array_flip($array);
```

Comment: And this is just theory, I haven't tested to see if it works, but I imagine it would.

Comment: That will fail if the there are duplicate values.

Comment: This will cause some problems if the there are duplicates in the value sets

Answer (score 0):

We are using this function for changing multiple array keys within an array keeping the order:

```
function replace_keys($array, $keys_map) {
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    foreach($keys_map as $old_key=>$new_key){
        if (false === $index = array_search($old_key, $keys)) {
            continue;
        }
        $keys[$index] = $new_key;
    }
    return array_combine($keys, array_values($array));
}
```

You can pass an array as $keys_map, like this:

```
$keys_map=array("old_key_1"=>"new_key_1", "old_key_2"=>"new_key_2",...)
```

This solution is based on Kristian one.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, one can also put the key to change at the end of the array in the moment of creation :

```
$array=array('key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2','keytochange'=>'value');
$x=$array['keytochange'];
unset($array['keytochange']);
$array['newkey']=$x;
```

Comment: One can also put many keys to change at the end and do it for all these keys

Answer (score -2):

You could use [array_combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php). It merges an array for keys and another for values...

For instance:

```
$original_array =('foo'=>'bar','asdf'=>'fdsa');
$new_keys       = array('abc', 'def');
$new_array      = array_combine($new_keys, $original_array);
```

Comment: what if you have many many keys and want to change just one? With your solution you would be obliged to write an endless $new_keys array.