# What is the most elegant way to change a key of an array by preserve the order

Tags: php

I have a big associative array with over 1 000 items and I want to rename one key but the order must be preserved.

I don't wont to iterate over the complete array and copy it into a new.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

Comment: You know the value of the key or you know the index of the key you want to change or both?

Comment: I only know the key name, not the index position

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the array_splice function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

this will do the job

Comment: Keys given as $replacement array will no preserved

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr[$newkey] = $arr[$oldkey];
unset($arr[$oldkey]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $array_keys = array_keys($array);

  $array_keys[array_search('old', $array_keys)] = 'new';

  $array = array_combine($array_keys, $array);
```

Comment: This is working but it copy's all keys into a new array which allocates much RAM on big arrays

Comment: Unfortunately I think any solution is going to involve the creation of (a) new array(s). I'd love to be wrong here.

Comment: From PHP's C-level it should be possible - but can't find a function to do so :(

Answer (score -2):

```
$array[$newkeyname] = $array[$oldkeyname];
unset($array[$oldkeyname]);
```

Comment: This is the same answer as one above, it doesn't answer the question. This does not preserve the order of the array.

Comment: sorry question was unanswered when i opened it.