# PHP - Associative arrays: Changing keys for key value pair where value is a class object

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an associative array of the form:

```
$input = array("one" => <class object1>,
               "two" => <class object2,
               ... //and so on);
```

The keys of $input are guaranteed to be unique. I also have a method called `moveToHead($key)` which moves the `$input[$key]` element to the 0th location of this associative array. I have few questions:

1. Is it possible to determine the index of an associative array?
2. How to move the array entry for corresponding `$key => $value` pair to the index 0 and retaining the `$key` as is?
3. What could be the best possible way to achieve both of the above points?

I was thinking to do array_flip for 2nd point (a sub solution), but later found out that `array_flip` can only be done when array elements are int and string only. Any pointers?

Comment: Is the fact that they keys are unique important to the question?

Comment: I guess no, but as a precautionary measure, I put it there so as to keep the discussion focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a function called `array_keys` you can determine the index of a key:

```
$keys = array_flip(array_keys($input));
printf("Index of '%s' is: %d\n", $key, $keys[$key]);
```

To insert an array at a certain position (for example at the beginning), there is the [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) function. So you can create the array to insert, remove the value from the old place and splice it in:

```
$key = 'two';
$value = $input[$key];
unset($input[$key]);    
array_splice($input, 0, 0, array($key => $value));
```

Something similar is possible with the [array union operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php), but only because you want to move to the top:

```
$key = 'two';
$value = $input[$key];
unset($input[$key]);
$result = array($key => $value) + $input;
```

But I think this might have more overhead than `array_splice`.

Comment: array_unshift - again O(n) time complexity due to reindexing involved.

Comment: I changed that code, I saw that it did too much. However no idea if you can really go away from O(n).

Comment: good thought, I just missed on that one. I will try this on my class objects and will let you know the results. thnx :)

Comment: Edited as I saw somebody else had the array union operator as well and made the array_splice example more prominent, I think it's a pretty good variant.

Comment: the array_splice thing is replacing the key with "0", but the second union operator is working just fine.

Comment: Right, the key is not taken over, I have overlooked that ([demo](http://codepad.org/85N9N8gz)). Please see as well: [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14218/discussion-between-ankit-garg-and-hakre)

Answer (score 1):

The "index" of an associative array is the key. In a numerically indexed array, the "key" is the index number.

**EDIT:** I take it back. PHP's associative arrays are ordered (like Ordered Maps in other languages).

But perhaps what you really want is an ordered array of associative arrays?

```
$input = array(array("one" => <class object1>),
               array("two" => <class object2>)
               //...
         );
```

Comment: PHP's arrays are ordered hashtables, so order is meaningful. Similar to what you have in other language with `ordered_map` etc ;)

Comment: PHP array keys _are_ ordered though! That's why we have functions like `ksort()`

Comment: I do have the implementation as described by @grammar31, but moving searching, deleting, moving all operations will have O(n) time complexity. However, I was thinking to do the same in O(1). If it is not possible in O(1), can we reduce the constant for linear time required?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I came up with:

```
$arr = array('one' => 'Value1', 'two' => 'Value2', 'three' => 'Value3');

function moveToHead($array,$key) {
   $return = $array;
   $add_val = array($key => $return[$key]);
   unset($return[$key]);
   return $add_val + $return;
}

print_r(moveToHead($arr,'two'));
```

results in

```
Array
(
    [two] => Value2
    [one] => Value1
    [three] => Value3
)
```

http://codepad.org/Jcb6ebxZ

Comment: will have to try for class objects. thnx anyway

Comment: It shouldn't matter what kind of data  or objects are in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use internal array pointer functions to do what you want:

```
$input = array(
    "one"   => "element one",
    "two"   => "element two",
    "three" => "element three",
);
reset($input); // Move to first element.
echo key($input); // "one"
```

You can `unset` the element out and put it in the front:

```
$input = array(
    "one"   => "element one",
    "two"   => "element two",
    "three" => "element three",
);
$key = "two";
$element = $input[$key];
unset($input[$key]);
// Complicated associative array unshift:
$input = array_reverse($input);
$input[$key] = $element;
$input = array_reverse($input);
print_r($input);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm also doing the same thing, but the whole point is, this takes two array_reverse function calls. array_reverse itself run in O(n) time complexity.