# Php array : change the key number with a word

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like this

```
<?php

Array (
        [0] => Array (
                        ['a'] =>'David'
                        ['b'] => 'Paul'
                        [0] => 'Tom'
                     )
        [1] => Array (
                        ['a'] =>'Andrea'
                        ['b'] => 'Chris'
                        [0] => 'Mark'
                     )
)
?>
```

i have to change the '0' key with a 'c'. how can i do it ?

Comment: Searching first is a good habit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233405/change-key-in-associative-array-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First copy the contents by simply setting `$array['c']` to `$array[0]` and then remove `$array[0]`:

```
$array['c'] = $array[0];
unset($array[0]);
```