# Change element of loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have an php array like this (var_dump)
   I need change one of it's element

```
  array (size=204)
          'Address' => 
            array (size=3)
              'City' => 
                array (size=3)
                  0 => string 'return $this->hasOne(City::className(), ['id' => 'cityId']);' 
                  1 => string 'City' (length=4)
                  2 => boolean false
              'CityDistrict' => 
                array (size=3)
                  0 => string 'return $this->hasOne(CityDistrict::className(), ['id' => 'cityDistrictId']);' (length=76)
                  1 => string 'CityDistrict' (length=12)
                  2 => boolean false
              'Contacts' => 
                array (size=3)
                  0 => string 'return $this->hasMany(Contact::className(), ['addressId' => 'id']);' 
                  1 => string 'Contact' (length=7)
                  2 => boolean true
          'City' => 
            array (size=3)
              'Addresses' => 
                array (size=3)
                  0 => string 'return $this->hasMany(Address::className(), ['cityId' => 'id']);' 
                  1 => string 'Address' (length=7)
                  2 => boolean true
              'Region' => 
                array (size=3)
                  0 => string 'return $this->hasOne(Region::className(), ['id' => 'regionId']);' (length=64)
                  1 => string 'Region' (length=6)
                  2 => boolean false
              'CityDistricts' => 
                array (size=3)
                  0 => string 'return $this->hasMany(CityDistrict::className(), ['cityId' => 'id']);' 
                  1 => string 'CityDistrict' (length=12)
                  2 => boolean true
          'CityDistrict' => 
            array (size=2)
              Addresses => 
                array (size=3)
                  0 => string 'return $this->hasMany(Address::className(), ['cityDistrictId' => 'id']);' 
                  1 => string 'Address' (length=7)
                  2 => boolean true
              'City' => 
                array (size=3)
                  0 => string 'return $this->hasOne(City::className(), ['id' => 'cityId']);'
                  1 => string 'City' (length=4)
                  2 => boolean false
```

How can i change value 'CityDistrict' in this loop? or 'Addresses'? using php foreach 
My code doesn't work please help understand what wrong!

```
  private static function checkExistClass($relations)
    {
        foreach ($relations as $name => $relation) {
            foreach ($relation as $functionName => $functionValue) {
                $functionNameGet = 'get' . $functionName;
                $directory = new Model;
                if (method_exists($directory, $functionNameGet)) {
                    $relation['funky_key_' . $functionName] = $functionValue;
                    unset($relation[$functionName]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $relations;
    }
```

Comment: One thing that isn't likely to work is that == in the argument to method_exists()...

Comment: @lserni: thank for answer i changed code but it doesn't help, see my changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interprete your question that you want to rename the array index Addresses to NewAddresses:

```
$relations['CityDistrict']['NewAddresses'] = $relations['CityDistrict']['Addresses'];
unset($relations['CityDistrict']['Addresses']);
```

---

EDIT:
to do that in your foreach loop, change:

```
$relation['funky_key_' . $functionName] = $functionValue;
unset($relation[$functionName]);
```

to:

```
$relations[$name]['funky_key_'.$functionName] = $functionValue;
unset($relations[$name][$functionName]);
```

Comment: Possibly `$relations[$name]['CityDistrict']` -- it *looks* at least like the array is deeper. Could even be `$relations[$name][$relation]['CityDistrict']`.

Comment: @Isemi: the var_dump doesn't look deeper :-)

Comment: thank for answer i changed code but it doesn't help, see my changes

Comment: @Anton Scherbinin: see EDIT

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you're looking

```
if (isset($array['n'])) {
  $array['name'] = $array['n'];
  unset($array['n']);
}
```

you can see the complete post in [Change key in associative array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233405/change-key-in-associative-array-in-php)

see you!

PD Sorry, for my english is not the best

Answer (score 0):

Your loop seems wrong. In the outer loop, `$name` assumes values such as 'Address', and `$relation` is an array such as { 'City' => ..., 'CityDistrict' => ... }.

So in the second loop `$functionName` assumes values such as City, CityDistrict and Contacts.

If you want to change *that*, you need to do something like @hellcode suggested:

```
if ('CityDistrict' == $functionName) {
    $relations[$name]['NewDistrict'] = $relations[$name][$functionName];
    unset($relations[$name][$functionName]);
    continue;
}
```

This looks like a `Laravel`/`Eloquent` problem to me. If you can state more precisely what it is that you're trying to accomplish, possibly someone could be of more use.

Also, you seem to want to **create a function given its code in a string**. To do this you would need `create_function` (or declare the function as anonymous/lambda function):

```
$code = "return 42;";

$array['function'] = create_function('', $code);

print $array['function']();
```

Note that the use of [create_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) is somewhat deprecated. Also you need a PHP > 5.3+ (or 5.4+ if you go lambda *and* require `$this`).