# How do I use Kohana ORM's values function when my form field names do not match the table column names?

Tags: php, orm, kohana, kohana-orm, kohana-3.3

I'm using Kohana 3.3 ORM and have setup the rules method for validation.  Now I would like to actually create a record to my table.  I want to populate all the values to my ORM object by calling `$ormtable->values($_POST)` but my problem is that not all of the field names in the $_POST array exactly match the column name in the table.

For example, my form has a field with the name "billing_address1" but the corresponding table column is "address1".

Is there some existing method in the ORM that does this already?  If not, what is the best way to map these alternate field names?

Comment: I don't believe there is a built in solution for this. Although you could easily copy `$_POST` to a temp array and manually [change the keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @kinakero said simply use temp array

```
$post_array = $_POST;
$post_array['address1'] = $_POST['billing_address1'];
unset($post_array['billing_address1']);

$ormtable->values($post_array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I ended up doing just that except wrapping it in a function that extends the Arr class and just passing two arrays, the source and one with the  mapping of keys that needed to be changed. https://gist.github.com/chadsaun/7043210

Comment: Nice solution. There is a `'` missing at the end of line 11 and the comment is probably self explanatory