# Change Index Key to Name

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I have built a multidimensional array for usage in a custom Wordpress query. Although it is Wordpress I feel that this is more a basic PHP question.

The array that I have now outputs everything properly, accept for the index value. I need it to be a string instead of an integer.

Here is what I need my ouput to be

```
Array (
    [post_type] => property
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [tax_query] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [taxonomy] => state
            [field] => slug
            [terms] => illinois
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [taxonomy] => illinois_county
            [field] => slug
            [terms] => fulton
        )
    )
)
```

And here is what is actually being output

```
Array (
    [post_type] => property
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [taxonomy] => state
            [field] => slug
            [terms] => illinois
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [taxonomy] => illinois_county
            [field] => slug
            [terms] => fulton
        )
    )
)
```

The only difference being the key of the second array which is `0` in mine and needs to be `tax_query`.

To get this Array I am declaring `$tax_query_array = array();` and then dropping my child arrays as needed depending on what variables are present in the url, such as `$tax_query_array[] = $state_array;` and `$tax_query_array[] = $county_array;`. Then finally calling `$tax_query_array` where i need the final multidimensional array output.

Only thing stopping me is the initial `[0]` which needs to instead be `[tax_query]`.

Here is the full code:

```
$tax_query_array = array();

$tax_query_array['tax_query'][] = $state_array;
$tax_query_array['tax_query'][] = $county_array;
$tax_query_array['tax_query'][] = $price_range_array;

$taxonomy_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    $tax_query_array
}
```

Output from changing `$tax_query_array[] = $county_array;` to `$tax_query_array['tax_query'][] = $county_array;` via MikeBrant:

```
Array (
    [post_type] => property
    [posts_per_page] => -1
    [0] => Array (
        [tax_query] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [taxonomy] => state
                [field] => slug
                [terms] => illinois
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [taxonomy] => illinois_county
                [field] => slug
                [terms] => fulton
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Change it in the code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

Comment: How are you getting this array? Any reason you can't just change the key as suggested above?

Comment: Edited for clarity for the questions

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$taxonomy_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query'=> array($state_array, $county_array, $price_range_array)
}
```

Comment: I think you need `$tax_query_array['tax_query'][] = $country_array;`

Comment: But `$country_array` is already an array you don't need to create another one

Comment: Yes, but look at his structure.  It has nested arrays inside `tax_query` element. If you take your approach, you would overwrite the entire element at that index rather than append a new entry to it.

Comment: This is true. The answer just rewrites the index to the last created array. The @MikeBrant answer almost gets you there in terms of the `tax_query` key being added, but it just nests the arrays one more level deep versus renaming the first key from `0` to `tax_query`.

Comment: @MikeBrant added your output to the question

Comment: Ahh I see.  I thought `$tax_query_array` was the full array that you are outputting.  This was not clear from your question.  I am not sure what that array name is (code examples would have helped here). What that full array is you  just need to do `$full_array['tax_query'][] = $country_array`;`$full_array['tax_query'][] = $state_array;` and similar.

Comment: Yes, this was not clear! $full_array['tax_query'][] is the solution.

Comment: Yes this seems to work. Instead of inserting the array that i was building into another array that was previously output as text, I had to build the entire thing, which is ok, and more efficient. But yes, this approach worked perfectly.