# array_combine with key has only one from array 1 and multiple values from array 2

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays:

array 1 I want it to be a keys(duplicate is ok) in array_combine:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => id
        [1] => user_id
        [2] => firstname
    )
```

And here's my array 2 that I wanted to be the values in array_combine:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 363
        [1] => 363
        [2] => Omotayo
    )

Array
    (
        [0] => 167
        [1] => 167
        [2] => Shafraaz
    )
```

Now challenge is, I have 2 arrays the first one has only one array and the second array has 2 inside arrays. The first array that I wanted to be the keys(duplicate) in array_combine. My desire output like below:

```
    Array
    (
        [id] => 363
        [user_id] => 363
        [firstname] => Omotayo
    )
    Array
    (
        [id] => 167
        [user_id] => 167
        [firstname] => Shafraaz
    )
```

Just wonder is there way to achieve this task? Appreciated any advise!!

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element Refer this

Comment: Not sure what you mean Hemnath?? Could you explain more details?

Comment: Is this output of preg_match?

Comment: No nhahtdh, just 2 arrays I extracted from csv array, and want to combine them together.

Comment: Are you sure you have equal number of elements within next array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just run array_combine on each inner array of `$array2`?

```
$final = array();
foreach($array2 as $array) {
    $final[] = array_combine($array1, $array);
}
```

This'll leave `$final` as the expected array with proper key/value pairs.

Comment: I have tried it before, and it threw an errors:
 Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Comment: What's the exact values of your variables? Like $array1 = ..., $array2 = ..., etc as the only reason you'd get that reason based on your question is if you were iterating over the individual elements of $array2 instead of each outer array maybe?

Comment: below are my 2 arrays 

$array1 = Array( id, user_id, firstname )

$array2 = Array([0] => array('363', '363', 'Omotayo'), [1] =>array('167', '167', 'Shafraaz'))

Comment: very strange, it fails in my environment with the loop :/

Comment: My PHP Version is 5.5.12. Were this a problem?

Comment: Just tested against 5.5.24. At this point, I'm out of ideas and if the exact code I posted in the ideone link isn't working in your environment, sounds like your environment is somehow borked.

Answer (score 1):

Please, test this method and see if it works on your environment:

```
$keys = array("id","user_id","firstname");
$values = array(
    array(363,363,"Omotayo"),
    array(167,167,"Shafraaz")
);
$out = array();
foreach($values as $ukey=>$user)
{
    foreach($user as $key=>$data)
    {
        $values[$ukey][$keys[$key]] = $data;
        unset($values[$ukey][$key]);
    }
}
print_r($values);
```