# Swapping out the first index of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$array = [
'foo' => 44,
'bar' => 77,
'moo' => 88,
];
```

Now I have two variables, $key and $value, and I want to replace the first index of the array. So remove foo and 44, and add $key and $value in their place.

So my array becomes:

```
$array = [
 $key => $foo,
 'bar' => 77,
 'moo' => 88,
];
```

How may I do this?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first element of the array:

`array_shift($array);`

Add the new key/value pair to the start of the array:

```
$array = array($key => $value) + $array;
```