# Renaming a key in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to change key name in a multidimensional array.

My array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [fruit namé] => Banana
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [fruit namé] => Apple
        )
)
```

My function:

```
function renameFields($old, $new, $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
        $arr[$k][$new] = $arr[$k][$old];
        unset($arr[$k][$old]);
    }
}

renameFields("fruit namé", "name", $arr);
```

-

It works for `id` but not when there an accent like `fruit namé`.

-

**EDIT**
I know it's a bad practice to have some special char as key, but this datas came from a French system...

Comment: Why are you doing `global $arr;` if you are passing `$arr` to your function?

Comment: I've removed it from the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either a) pass `$arr` to your function by *reference* or b) have `renameFields` return the updated array.

Your code currently modifies a copy of the `$arr` array (because that's what gets passed to `renameFields` when it's called), and never updates the one that exists *outside* of the `renameFields` function.

So, you need to either do:

```
function renameFields($old, $new, &$arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
        $arr[$k][$new] = $arr[$k][$old];
        unset($arr[$k][$old]);
    }
}

renameFields("fruit name", "name", $arr);
```

Which will pass `$arr` by reference.

Or:

```
function renameFields($old, $new, $arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
        $arr[$k][$new] = $arr[$k][$old];
        unset($arr[$k][$old]);
    }

    return $arr;
}

$arr = renameFields("fruit name", "name", $arr);
```

Which will have the function return the updated array and then you need to then update the variable.

P.S. You don't need `global $arr;` in either case here.

Comment: Both solutions made the same. The `fruit name` is still here, and it added at the end of the array a new key called `name`.

Comment: @pocpoc: Both worked fine for me: http://codepad.org/49Uyac6k and http://codepad.org/cETp3doJ

Comment: Since he is using global in the original function, it shouldn't be a copy of the array, but the actual array itself that he is modifying. However, this would be the more correct way.

Comment: Hum... Strange. I will look into this.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: But would the `global $arr;` conflict with the `$arr` parameter?

Comment: As my array comes from a French system, my real key got some accent. In this case, the two solution will not work. Do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: `global $arr` would mean that looping over and modifying `$arr` in the function makes the changes to the array outside of the function. In fact, op's original function works fine. http://codepad.viper-7.com/TxldcG

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: yes except for the accent.

Comment: @pocpoc You would need to spell the strings you pass into the function exactly as they exist in the array, with accent characters and case exactly the same. Unless you wanted to loop over each sub-key and check it's value in a case insensitive/translit method.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: My question was whether `global $arr;` and the fact that  `$arr` was the 3rd parameter would conflict.

Comment: @pocpoc without sample data that covers the exact scenario with the issue, then we can't do much more as from what we have, the function works fine. And @Rocket, I have no idea. I just tried modifying OP's function by adding a 3rd parameter and it didn't seem to cause any issues. http://codepad.viper-7.com/m6XFez shows that calling `global` actually overwrites the array inside of the function with the global one and after the loop it modifies the global array, not the one passed in.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: Oh, then I guess OP's original code worked and the *real* issue is the UTF8/accented character issue.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: your guess right. I've changed few minutes ago the question. For your help.

Comment: Just got me wondering too, if the third argument is passed in by reference will calling global on the variable overwrite the referenced variable with the global one. http://codepad.viper-7.com/Nw4Cep, and it appears that calling global actually breaks the reference making the loop not edit the referenced variable.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a good idea to use spaces in your key names. You can do it but it's bad practice.

Here is what I came up with:

```
$my_array = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'fruit name' => 'Banana'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'fruit name' => 'Apple'
    )
);

function renameFields($old, $new, $arr) {
    $new_a = array();
    foreach ($arr as $a) {
        $new_a[] = array(
            'id' => $a['id'],
            $new => $a[$old] 
        );
    }
    return $new_a;
}

$new_array = renameFields("fruit name", "name", $my_array);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
echo "</pre>";
```

It is a much better idea to pass the array to the function rather than using a global.

Comment: Why is it "bad practice" to use spaces in key names?

Comment: php couldn't care less what characters are in a key name. they're just strings, after all. It might be "bad practice" in OTHER languages, like js, where you can use `array.key` as a short-hand access notation, instead of `array[key]`.

Comment: I guess it really is NOT bad practice to have spaces in key names but more of a preference. Most companies that set a standards for naming don't use spaces in key names. By not using spaces it just keeps naming conventions standard across the board.

Comment: most? mayb esome, but not all, and the nice thing about conventions, is that they're like standards: so many to choose from.