# How to rename an array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [fee_id] => 15
        [fee_amount] => 308.5
        [year] => 2009                
    )
```

I want change the name of parent to this:

```
'searchResult' => Array
    (
        [fee_id] => 15
        [fee_amount] => 308.5
        [year] => 2009                
    )
```

How is possible ?

Comment: How is it not? Check the first answer in the linked; it says how to change the name of the key of an array-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what i want!

```
 $searchRs['searchRs'] = $resultArr->d;
 unset($resultArr->d);
 return $searchRs;
```

Comment: As I told you, that's exactly the same answer as the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element).

Answer (score 1):

something like this would be possible:

```
<?php
//keep it in the same variable
$array['searchResult'] = $array[0];
unset($array[0]);

//create a new variable
$new_array = array('searchResult'=>$array[0]);
?>
```