# Change the index of an array

Tags: php

I need help to change the index of an array.

I have this array:

```
$items = array('items' => array(
    0 => array(
        'item_id' => 1,
        'item_amount' => 100,
    ),
    1 => array(), 
));
```

Now I want to remove the index, based on the value of `item_id`, but I don't know how to do this.

I've tried to do it as follows, but doesn't work.

```
foreach($items['items'] as $key) {
  $removeIndex = $key['item_id'] == 1;
  if($removeIndex) {
     unset($removeIndex);
  }  
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: do you want to just remove the `item_id` from the array if it's value is `1` ?

Comment: You'd rather need to unset the actual array element, like `unset($key['item_id']);`. But that would as well only reset the element in the current subarray copy.

Comment: You are just unsetting the `$removeIndex` variable instead of the actual array item `unset($items['items'][$key])`

Comment: Yes, but I'm failing :(

Comment: @AmandaThompson, ok. Show us the final expected result

Comment: For the title: [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `unset` like this:

```
foreach($items['items'] as $index => $key) { // also get the index!
  if (!isset($key['item_id'])) continue; // skip
  $removeIndex = $key['item_id'] == 1;
  if($removeIndex) {
     unset($items['items'][$index]['item_id']); // specify path to that entry
  }  
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/606326).

To unset something in your nested array structure, you need to act on that array itself. `unset($removeIndex)` does not change the array, because that is a boolean value.

The extra `if` is there for the case when you don't have an `item_id` in some sub-array: in that case that iteration of the loop is skipped.

#### Removing the entire "row"

If your aim is to also remove the sub-array to which the `item_id` belongs (so including the `item_amount` and any other value in that sub-array), then just shorten the "path" in the `unset` statement:

```
foreach($items['items'] as $index => $key) { // also get the index!
  if (!isset($key['item_id'])) continue; // skip
  $removeIndex = $key['item_id'] == 1;
  if($removeIndex) {
     unset($items['items'][$index]); // specify path to that entry
  }  
}
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/606325).

Comment: Thank you so much @trincot! You helped me alot. :D. And thank for the others for the answers, I appreciate.

Comment: Hey @trincot. Script unsetting all items :(

Comment: Which one of the two versions are you using?

Comment: The second version

Comment: Could you edit your question and add more data for your array, enough to see the problem? I have added some data myself on eval.in, but I don't see a problem: https://eval.in/606325

Comment: Yes. The problem isn't in your code! I'll start a chat to descrbie more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the specific entry `'item_id'` in the `$items` array, you have to refer to it and use both keys, like in:

```
foreach($items['items'] as $key => $val) {
  if (!isset($val['item_id'])) continue;
  $removeIndex = $val['item_id'] == 1;
  if($removeIndex)
     unset($items['items'][$key]);
}
```

If you downvote, please state why you think this answer is not appropriate.

Comment: Nope, that was intentionally, but in the end it is still unclear what the OP wants to get. It is only so hard to find that out via comments. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `unset($items['items'][0])`. For your case it will be something like this:

```
$id = 1;
$keyToRemove = false;

foreach ($items['items'] as $key => $value) {
  if ($value['item_id'] == $id) {
    $keyToRemove = $key;
    break;
  };
}

if ($keyToRemove) {
  unset($items['items'][$keyToRemove]);
}
```