# how to change value in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$rows = array_map(function($item) {
return (object) ['c' => [
    (object) ['v' => $item->job_type, 'f' => null],
    (object) ['v' => intval($item->count), 'f' => null]
]];
}, array_values($data));

echo json_encode($data);
```

The output is like this:

```
{"1":{"job_id":"1","count":"8","job_type":"0"},"3":{"job_id":"3","count":"7","job_type":"1"}}
```

I want to change the value of job type from "0" to "job" and "1" to Internship.

How can i do that?

Comment: this may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

Comment: have another array (or class) that defines that strings.`$jobTypes = [0=>'job',..]`. Then have smth like `'v' => $jobTypes[$item->job_type],..`

Comment: I am sorry, but still confusing. I cannot change the value of the array.

Comment: can someone give help?