# how to replace var {$key} in array php key => aulue

Tags: php

I needed an assistant

about replace for simple variables:

```
$html = '<{$headtype} class="{$class}">{$text}</{$headtype}>';
$array['headtype']  = 'h1';
$array['class']     = 'classname';
$array['text']      = 'the title'; 
// result
<h1 class="classname">the title</h1>
```

Knowing that the array is variable in keys and values

Answer (score 1):

You can set the array key and old key to unset like that,
`$arr[$newkey] = $arr[$oldkey]; unset($arr[$oldkey]);` 
More information you can check below article.
[change the key of an array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate through the array and use [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace the strings:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $html = str_replace('{$'.$key.'}', $value, $html);
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/PceWI

Answer (score 0):

```
$array['headtype']  = 'h1';
$array['class']     = 'classname';
$array['text']      = 'the title'; 
extract($array)
$html = '<{$headtype} class="{$class}">{$text}</{$headtype}>';
```

is what you want if i get the question right. please comment below and i will update my answer as you want.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. You still need to replace them in the string (which is what the OP actually is asking about). And if you're trying to resolve the variables inside the string, the string needs to be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: thank you for your reply, i will update my answer in few minutes.

Comment: I would also recommend against using `extract()` since it clutters the variable scope and can result in unwanted results (if the scope already contains any of those variables).

Comment: Thank geekido ..
Used
extract( $array );
$press = preg_replace('/\{\$([a-z]+)\}/e', "$$1", $html);

The result was as I wanted
If you have a better code I wish you would place us for the benefit

Comment: thank you @HossamMega i've been searching, i will update when i find out better code