# PHP .txt to array tab delimited

Tags: php, arrays, tabs

**Hello. im having this code:**

```
public function parse_reports($filename)
{    
    $result = array();
    $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
    if (($headers = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE)
      if ($headers)
        while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) 
          if ($line)
            if (sizeof($line)==sizeof($headers))
              $result[] = array_combine($headers,$line);
    fclose($fp);
    return $result; //return result
}
```

**and my array list its like:**

```
Array
( //test array1
    [0] => Array
        ( //array 0
            [VNUM] => 1
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Yang
        )

    [1] => Array
        ( //array 1
            [VNUM] => 2
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Ελληνική Έκδοση
        )

    [2] => Array
        ( //array 2
            [VNUM] => 10
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Σπαθί+0
        )

    [3] => Array
        ( //array 3
            [VNUM] => 11
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Σπαθί+1
        )
```

**what i need is for array numbers to take VNUM Number for example looks like this:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [VNUM] => 1 //this take the value of VNUM
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Yang
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [VNUM] => 2 //this take the value of VNUM
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Ελληνική Έκδοση
        )

    [10] => Array //this take the value of VNUM
        (
            [VNUM] => 10 //this take the value of VNUM
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Σπαθί+0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [VNUM] => 11 //this take the value of VNUM
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Σπαθί+1
        )
```

***as you can see what i need is to change arrays id with the VNUM that my .txt header have...if someone could help me with this i would be very happy! thank you!***
if you need any more details feel free to ask me

***Fixed thanks to Eddie***

Comment: I would just save the proper key to start with from the vnum, as array is practically just a map(key+value) and you don't have to use number indexes. But if you have to change the key for your array, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce`

Note: I have to use `implode` and `explode` for this since there are hidden/special characters on text file.

Like:

```
public function parse_reports($filename)
{    
    $result = array();
    $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
    if (($headers = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE)
      if ($headers)
        while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) 
          if ($line)
            if (sizeof($line)==sizeof($headers))
              $result[] = array_combine($headers,$line);
    fclose($fp);

    //To use the VNUM as the key
    $result = array_reduce($result,function($c,$v){
        $val = explode( ",", implode( ",", $v ));
        $c[ $val[0] ] = $v;
        return $c;
    }, array());

    return $result;
}
```

---

Getting this result

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [VNUM] => 1
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Yang
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [VNUM] => 2
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Ελληνική Έκδοση
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [VNUM] => 10
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Σπαθί+0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [VNUM] => 11
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Σπαθί+1
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [VNUM] => 12
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Σπαθί+2
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [VNUM] => 13
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Σπαθί+3
        )
......
```

Doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: VNUM in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wiki\include\class\class.equipment.php on line 54 :/

Comment: Can you post a sample text file? Ill try to recreate it

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aAZCD1KdGaZ7HB0QgGZ2A4WU2XdgynMQ/view?usp=sharing thanks for your time!

Comment: same error :/ 
Notice: Undefined index: VNUM in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wiki\include\class\class.equipment.php on line 54

Comment: OMG! Happy to help.

Comment: Not sure why the name bit didn't work, but just a suggestion - the `array_reduce()` could be made redundant by changing the initial point where the array is loaded... `$result[] = array_combine($headers,$line);` could be `$result[$line[0]] = array_combine($headers,$line);`

Comment: I sended you email for something else on this fuction if you could help me! thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_column()` like...

```
return array_column ($result, null, 'VNUM'); //return result
```

This uses the VNUM column as an index to the array.

**Update:**
It's possible that your column headers may include whitespace and therefore `array_column()` won't work as it is, but if you try...

```
public function parse_reports($filename)
{    
    $result = array();
    $fp = fopen($filename, "r");
    if (($headers = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE)
      if ($headers)
        $headers = array_map("trim", $headers );
        while (($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) 
          if ($line)
            if (sizeof($line)==sizeof($headers))
              $result[] = array_combine($headers,$line);
    fclose($fp);
    return array_column ($result, null, 'VNUM'); //return result
}
```

This will clean up any header value in the `array_map()` call.

**Update (2):**

Looks as though there is something odd with the headers - one last attempt...

```
return array_column($result, null, $headers[0]);
```

Sample data...

```
VNUM    LOCALE_NAME
1   Yang
2   Ελληνική Έκδοση
10  Σπαθί+0
11  Σπαθί+1
12  Σπαθί+2
13  Σπαθί+3
14  Σπαθί+4
15  Σπαθί+5
16  Σπαθί+6
17  Σπαθί+7
18  Σπαθί+8
19  Σπαθί+9
```

Comment: return array_column ($result, 'LOCALE_NAME', 'VNUM'); if i do this like this its working perfectly but this will be not good cause i want to add more fields like:
            [VNUM] => 11 //this take the value of VNUM
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Σπαθί+1
            [phone] => 69000000
how will i do it; :/

Comment: Thats why you pass null as the second paramter.  This indexes the whole array and not a particular column.

Comment: with null its exacly the same code as it was:
    [0] => Array
        (
            [VNUM] => 1
            [LOCALE_NAME] => Yang
        )

Comment: If using ` 'LOCALE_NAME'` works, then using `null` should give the full array - that is nothing to do with how it's indexed.

Comment: With null:
https://prnt.sc/ilr3bc
with LOCALE_NAME:
https://prnt.sc/ilr3iw

i want it like the LOCALE_NAME one but to print and other columns if i add not only those two :/

Comment: Neither of those calls has worked properly, I've updated the answer with some code to try and clean up the headers, can you try the updated code.

Comment: One last try - change return to `return array_column($result, null, $headers[0]);`

Comment: I've tried with your sample data and the above code works, so no idea what problem your having.

Comment: but i tried with the same :/ can you upload the files to check them??

Comment: I've added a segment of the file you uploaded, can you try that to test.

Comment: it works on you cause
VNUM LOCALE_NAME its not tab delimited but with spaces... so this is count as 1 value and it take it :/

Comment: Can you edit the file (just do the first couple of lines and delete the rest), it may be to do with the copy/paste at my end.