# How to change the key in associative array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this:

```
Array (
   [0] => Aenean
   [1] => Lorem
   [2] => Morbi
)
```

I am try using `foreach` to make array above format be associative array. Trying to change the `key` (e.g. 0,1,2) to be another value (e.g. x,y,z).

```
array(
    'x' => 'Aenean',
    'y' => 'Lorem',
    'z' => 'Morbi'
),
```

So far, I try using foreach but give me wrong result

```
    $r_cat = array (Aenean,Lorem,Morbi);

    $cs = array();
    foreach ($r_cat as $c ) {
     $cs [] .= array (get_cat_ID($c) => $c);
    }
    print_r ($cs);
```

RESULT

```
Array (
   [0] => Array
   [1] => Array
   [2] => Array
)
```

Comment: `$cs[get_cat_ID($c)] = $c;` ?

Comment: `$cs [] .=` makes little sense to begin with, `.=` is for string concatenation. `$cs[] =` would be the correct way to add new entries to a numeric array - but you want to specify the associative key here, so you must actually do that - `$cs['somekey'] =`

Comment: this is function in wordpress to get id from categoy name

Comment: Is `get_cat_ID()` the source of the associative key?

Comment: Related: [Replace keys in an array based on another lookup/mapping array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71274431/2943403)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
$array = ['Aenean', 'Lorem', 'Morbi'];

$array = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[get_cat_ID($item)] = $item;

    return $carry;
}, []);

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP `array_combine()` function to set key from one array and values from the second array. No need to use the loop :

```
$a = array('x','y','z');
$b = array('Aenean','Lorem','Morbi');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

echo '<pre>';print_r($c); echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [x] => Aenean
    [y] => Lorem
    [z] => Morbi
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    0 => 'Aenean',
    1 => 'Lorem',
    2 => 'Morbi'
);

$i = 0;

$keyValues = array('x','y','z');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $cs[$keyValues[$i]] = $value;
    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($cs);
```

And the output is :

```
Array
(
    [x] => Aenean
    [y] => Lorem
    [z] => Morbi
)
```

I made a test array with some example values you want to put (x,y,z as you mentioned) and replaced your keys inside the foreach like you tried as well.

Another way is to use the `key` value in your foreach and replace it with the new one and after unset your old key like below:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    0 => 'Aenean',
    1 => 'Lorem',
    2 => 'Morbi'
);

$i = 0;

$keyValues = array('x','y','z');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$keyValues[$i]] = $array[$key];
    unset($array[$key]);
    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
```