# Change the key of an array

Tags: php

I have an array that contains year as follows. This key is going to be dynamic. NowI want to replace new_2018 to "2018".

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "new_2018" => "john",
    )
);
```

I have tried following approach. This is also working fine. But regarding quality I am not sure. Can anybody help me improve the quality of this code.

```
$newArr = array();
foreach ($array as $value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $val) {
        list($a, $year) = explode('_', $key);
        $newArr[][$year] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your data structur seems a bit weird. Why do you add `new_` when you want to remove it?... what if you split your data to year, status and name instead ?

Comment: this new_ is coming from query which I am not allowed to modify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In PHP, how do you change the key of an array element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240660/in-php-how-do-you-change-the-key-of-an-array-element)

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code

Comment: @MaximFedorov yes it can be duplicate but in my case I new_2018 is not fixed.. it can be any value with new_

Comment: @executable if not problem then thats ok . because i saw in SO other using array_walk  and pointer so I thought my code is not good

Answer (score 0):

it is ugly, but... and be careful with accessing by reference - don't forget to unset the variable:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    array(
        "new_2018" => "john",
    )
);

foreach ($array as &$value) {
    foreach($value as $key => $val) {
        $newKey = str_replace("new_", "", $key);
        $value[$newKey] = $val;
        unset($value[$key]);
    }
}
unset($value);

var_dump($array);
```