# Can a decoded json string element be used as an array key in find/replace using the json data as an array map?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

This is not the same question as "Replace keys in an array based on another lookup/mapping array" because the map array does not use numerical keys.

I am being given json data from a third party that contains multidimensional arrays.  The third party has recently updated their software which resulted in a change of approx 256 column names.  To keep the data compatible with my existing tables/code, I need to change some of the key names using an array as a map.  A snipped of the map with key=>value pairs:

```
    $map = [
    'projectId' =>'project_id',
    'projectName' => 'project_name',
    'purchaseOrderId' => 'purchase_order_id',
    'readOnly' => 'read_only',
    'readOnlyDescription' => 'read_only_description',
    'receivedDate' => 'received_date',
    'shipFromAddressId' => 'ship_from_address_id',
    'shippingInstructions' => 'shipping_instructions',
    'shipToAddressId' => 'ship_to_address_id',
    'shortName' => 'short_name',
    'specialCode' => 'special_code'
    ];
```

A snippet of the json data (this is flat for purposes of this question):

```
$array = [
    'projectid' => '140d0b2b-8538-4353-a90a-bc9d5979b03c',
    'projectname' => '230041 Test Project',
    'createdate' => '2023-04-25T10:55:55.146188',
    'modifieddate' => '2023-12-15T08:38:50.1736124-05:00',
    'biddate' => '2023-04-25T10:55:55.1599415',
    'gooduntildate' => '2023-05-25T10:55:55.1599415',
    'jobref' => '230041',
    'projectaddressid' => '66f2503e-55af-4c33-87ac-5f45770ac0e4',
    'freightselloverride' => 0.0,
    'freighttaxable' => true,
    'installationtaxable' => false,
    ];
```

Among my attempts so far (edited per @Barmar request):

```
function array_rename(&$array, $map)
{

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array ($value)) {

            $array[$key] = array_rename ($value);
        } elseif (!is_array ($value)) {

            if (isset($map[$key])) {
                $var = $map['projectId'];
                $array[$map[$key]] = $value;
                unset($array[$key]);
            }

        }
    }
    print_r ($array);
}

array_rename($array, $map);
```

When a key that comes up that needs to be changed (projectId to project_id for example), and $key is "projectId", I cannot find a way to use $map[$key] to return the element 'project_id' from $map['projectId'].  $var=$map['projectId'] returns "project_id"...$map[$key] returns null...  I believe it is the double quotes around the element causing the issue but I can't find a work around.

Desired result is $array['project_id' => '140d0b2b-8538-4353-a90a-bc9d5979b03c', etc...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the above code `array_rename()`? Does it end with `return $array;`?

Comment: Please post a [mre] showing how you call the function. If `$map` is a global variable, do you have `global $map;` in the function?

Comment: @startingout see my advice at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71274431/2943403 there is a fair amount of low-quality answers on that page (with too many upvotes) which misunderstood the task.  If you have an incoming key that is not listed in your translation array, then you can just save the the value with the original key (my answer excludes any elements which are not found).

Comment: @sta after correcting the map's keys, this is the implementation of my advice in the dupe target: https://3v4l.org/PePUE  (the lookup keys need to be case-sensitively identical to match)

Comment: @mickmackusa - "after correcting the map's keys" set me on the right path!  array_change_key_case ($map).  Thank you!